# Spring quartz overwrite-existing-jobs not compatible with misfire feature

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

When I set `overwrite-existing-jobs = true`, it always delete and insert my trigger info when server start. And later misfire feature always tell there is 0 job misfired.

So I can't have both feature enable?

Or is there any workaround? Like update the trigger instead of delete and insert.

I am using spring-boot-starter-quartz 2.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: Have you got any update on this. I am also facing this issue.

Comment: @MohitArora I create the trigger by myself when server start, seems it somehow work as expected. But it just a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, will try to implement that.